# WAMP 3 Server configuration

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, wamp

I require assistance configuring my WAMP server to allow Computer on my networks access a website on the server.

Installation of WAMP 3 server on a computer with a static ip goes well, no hiccups, and I can get the server running pretty easily on the local host. I create my directory a c:/wamp64/www/myproject, and I proceed to install the website that is already coded, its a mysql front end called Ennhanced SQL protal from www.eliacom.com

Now the local instance works well, and I can do the following:

localhost:8080/myproject and my website shows up nicely

if i put:

ipadressofserverPC:8080/myproject, it also loads up

If i go to another PC, and i write

ip-address-of-server:8080/myproject

It gives me error 403 forbidden.

Any ideas?

I am already familiar with editing the file on the server, just point me to a file and call the edits I'll try to get it working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default WAMP only serves localhost. To change this edit the following config files

Replace `Require local` - line 11 in file `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` with `Require all Granted`

Replace `Require local` - line 279 in file `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf\httpd.conf`the `<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/">` section with `Require all Granted`

Make sure that in each section there is only one `require` statement and the 'all' is lowercase.

Then Restart the WAMP server.

Comment: I am pretty sure I went thru all the .conf files to set it up correctly, I've seen to many different answers and if i try them all eventually the servers screws up. Give me some mins to check out if thats commented out, it should be.

Comment: I just reinstalled WAMP, & updated my awnser. You should have `Require All Granted` instead of `Require Local`

Comment: I have just altered... indeed the .conf files did read Require local instead of require all granted. Will report tomorrow how we did with that.

Comment: your answer is technically correct, with one error, if you place All, ALL, or any combination except 'all' it doesn't work, you get a syntax error and the server never restarts properly. So, I'll mark you answer as correct but be kind enough to change it and specify if needs to be 'all' for the 'require' command otherwise you get an error. @mt025

Comment: And you dont need to alter the `httpd.conf` file at all, as that host gets ignored when Virtual Hosts are used, which is why there is a VH for localhost in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file